# Title: operator and searching for answers written by a particular user

Tags: support, search

Lets suppose I'd like to find all answers of a particular user. I currently can do this through the `user` operator: `user:1234`.

What I'd additionally like to do would be to refine those search results so that the answers of the user are only from a `thread` that has `xyz` in the thread's title. I.e. search for answers of user `12345` which he wrote answering a thread (~a topic) whose title was: `xyz`.

As I've just learned, to accomplish this, it is currently impossible to use the `title:` operator, because the `title:` operator *excludes* answers from search results, because answers don't have a title.

The question: could an additional operator be introduced so that it would be possible to search for all answers of a given user, which (the answers) the user has written in response to a question whose title was `xyz`? That additional operator would match questions *and answers* from a thread (from a ~question) whose title is `xyz`.

Example:

[image]

[image]

In the second screenshot, the `title:` operator removed all answers of the user from search results, even though the title of the question the user provided answers for contains the word `Vim`.

For more details, see the previous revision of this question.

Comment: `progid` only matches whole words, the word `CLSIDFromProgID` in  a title is never considered.

Comment: Since only questions have titles, yes, I'd expect a `title` search to only match questions. [`[com] [clsid] title:clsidfromprogid`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcom%5D+%5Bclsid%5D+title%3Aclsidfromprogid) returns 1 result, the question with `CLSIDFromProgID` in the title.

Comment: added second example

Comment: Why would the second example ever match anything? There are *no* posts with those tags *and* that term in the title. That term is only ever found in an answer body, so the fact that the second search returned no matches is entirely correct.

Comment: Better example: [`[com] [progid] automation`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcom%5D+%5Bprogid%5D+automation) and [`[com] [progid] title:automation`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcom%5D+%5Bprogid%5D+title%3Aautomation). The first matches both the question and answer, the second only the question, because only questions have a title to match against.

Comment: @MartijnPieters right, what I wanted to do was to find a thread that has `HKCR` in the title, but the body of the question doesn't reference `HKCR`, only the answer post does... which wasn't what I ended up doing. I'll update the post again, thanks.

Comment: When you do *not* use `title:`, titles are still included in the searched text. `title:` should only be used to *limit* the search to words in the question title.

Comment: I am entirely unclear exactly what your question is here, really.

Comment: To clarify: the question is about: how to search for question or answer posts from the thread, whose (*thread's*) title contains a given word. When the `title` operator is used, search results are *question* posts only. I'd like the search results to be both questions *and answers* [from the thread whose title contains xyz].

Comment: We don't call questions 'threads' around here. Just call them questions.

Comment: The fact that `title` only returns questions **is entirely logical**. Just click on the question, and you'll see the answers. It is not the answers that matched, after all.

Comment: Right, to clarify: I've used the word `thread` to remove the ambiguity of what I've originally meant. So perhaps the real question is: should there be (or is it possible to have) a distinction between the title of the question and the title of the thread in the search query. The *thread* being what the question at the top of this page describes, more or less.

Comment: But the title at the top is part of the *question*. Answers are attached to a question, the title is not part of the answers. The question consists of a title and a body. Answers only consist of a body.

Comment: I understand. So it can't be done because of the internal design?

Comment: I don't understand **why** you need this to return answer posts; If this matched answers too, all you'd get is a list with the question and **all** answers on that question. That doesn't add anything here. You need to tell us **what advantage** there would be if answers were included.

Comment: Because answers don't have a distinct title, there is *nothing to distinguish them **from the question***

Comment: Originally this was meant to search for answers of a particular user, but I didn't want to include the userID in the post. If `title` would match answers, the search query could be refined to only match answers of a particular user.

Comment: **Now** we are getting somewhere. You should have made your question about that in the first place. You could have used your own userid as an example instead, surely?

Comment: Surely I could if I'd thought about it. Sadly this hasn't happened ;)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I don't get the logic behind this. So the title is part of the question, but tags are part of the thread? If I search for `[aura-framework] "assign"` I get one *answer* in my result which would mean that tags are part of the thread... Furthermore, if I only search for *tags*, I *can* get a result that is: list of whole threads (vs posts that are either q's or a's). Is there a place where I could read more on how the internals of the search mechanism work / could you elaborate on what were the design premises behind making the search to search for posts instead of threads?